# Javascript converting null to a string performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

According to v8 hidden classes, one should initiate the variables with a datatype, which should remain the same datatype to keep code execution performant. For example, if I have an array of `integers`, I ideally shouldn't add strings to it, as it will change the underlying hidden class for that initial array.

Here is an article on same http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/.

Now when i want to save a string to a variable, should i initialize it with `null` or an `empty string`.

```
var name = null
function setName (userName) {
  name = userName
}

// or 

var name = ''
function setName (userName) {
  name = userName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just set an variable, um don`t need put null or ''.

```
var name;
function setName (userName) {
  name = userName;
}
```

Comment: I think he's specifically asking about what would be the best option performance wise (and that one should initiate the variables with a datatype, btw).

Comment: Yes, does specifying nothing sets default data type to `string`? It will be `undefined` so assigning a string later will cause change to underlying hidden class